# Is Javascript is linked Dynamically or statically with the html?

Tags: javascript, java, html

As per my research in context of Java
If a class "A.java" is dependent on some function present in library file B.jar. It is said to be dynamically linked. because code in B.jar gets linked to the "A.java" at runtime producing executable.

Statically linked means the the code in B.jar is brought and compiled with the "A.java" before runtime.

But how does we should look at it when it comes to "C.html" and "D.js". How both are combined?

As working of **V8** engine says it has 2 compilers which at the end spits out optimized version of the "D.js" code. How this gets along with the "C.html"?

Consider "C.html" has

```
//Link D.js file 
<script type="text/javascript" src=**"D.js"**></script>
// loadDoc() is defined inside D.js file
 <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

Assume D.js file defines the loadDoc()

```
 function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  }
  };
 xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
 xhttp.send();
 }
```

Now this D.js is liked statically or dynamically?

Comment: The "context of Java" is in no way relevant to Javascript: they are two separate languages. And Java isn't statically linked.

Comment: "Java to javascript is the same as ham to hamster." Any insight you have in java is almost useless in javascript context. Especially when it comes to execution process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript and HTML are linked no way!

It's just that Web browser loads JavaScript source files into a scope where they can gain access to the [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), [Browser Object Model (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Object_Model) and HTML5 APIs in order to interact with them and vice versa.

In other words, HTML is just an expressive way of defining the structure of a given document and it's taken by the Web browser to render/paint a page and create a programmatic object model to interact with it, while JavaScript is a programming language that can interact with the UI thanks to the object model (DOM/BOM) and a set of APIs defined by the HTML5 evolving standards.

So HTML, CSS and JavaScript aren't dynamically or statically linked. They're just collaborators in order to provide structure, styling and behavior to a given Web page.

Comment: Thanks! but still I think Collaboration defines some form of linkage right? I am not wrong you mean to say there is no linkage between html, css and js instead they are all linked with web browser and web browser processes each of them separately. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DineshRavi Your 2nd description is better. There's no linkage... It's just they're used to build a representation of a Web page in memory...

Comment: One more thing! how about js to js dependency? this relation seems off for that scenario. will it work the same?

Comment: @DineshRavi JS to JS... JS is interpreted or compiled to byte code depending on the implementation. Thus, depending on that yes, it might be dynamically linked